# Equivalent of #define in tcl?

Tags: tcl, c-preprocessor

Is there a command in tcl that is equivalent to C++ #define? I've seen ways to implement "define" using overloading of the proc function, just wanted to know if anyone knows of a more starightforward way

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? Compile-time hacking has little value in dynamic languages.

Comment: I have a function that repeats alot and receives the same arguments: foo $a $b $c $d and foo $a $b $c $e 
so I wanted to define foo_e and foo_d instead of all of that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tcl has a mechanism that lets you define [aliases to procedures](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/interp.htm#M8) in an interpreter.

If you have

```
proc foo {one two three} {do something with $one $two $three}
```

and you find you're always passing $a and $b as the first two arguments, you can write:

```
interp alias {} foo_ab {} foo $a $b
```

And now you can say:

```
foo_ab $d   ;# same as "foo $a $b $d"
foo_ab $e   ;# same as "foo $a $b $e"
```

example:

```
proc foo {one two three} {puts [join [list $one $two $three] :]}
set a Hello
set b World
interp alias {} foo_ab {} foo $a $b
foo_ab example  ;# prints "Hello:World:example"
```

The empty braces in the `interp alias` command merely signify the current interpreter. You can do lots of fun things with slave interpreters.

Answer (score 5):

The use of `interp alias` allows you to use the contents of `a` and `b` at the time the alias was created:

```
interp alias {} foo_ab {} foo $a $b
```

If you need to use the values at the time it is called, you need a helper procedure instead:

```
proc foo_ab args {
    global a b
    uplevel 1 [list foo $a $b {*}$args]
    # Or this in older Tcl: uplevel 1 [list foo $a $b] $args
}
```

In 8.5, this can also be written with aliases and `apply`:

```
interp alias {} foo_ab {} apply {args {
    global a b
    uplevel 1 [list foo $a $b {*}$args]
}}
```

In 8.6, you can optimize further by using `tailcall`:

```
interp alias {} foo_ab {} apply {args {
    global a b
    tailcall foo $a $b {*}$args
}}
```

You could also use some other, dirtier tricks like this:

```
interp alias {} foo_ab {} namespace inscope :: {foo $a $b}
```

That's not especially fast though, but it does work in all Tcl 8.* versions.

Comment: If your variables `a` and `b` aren't global in scope, you can replace `global a b` with `upvar 1 a a; upvar 1 b b` to access them in the proc/apply

Comment: It's a shame that aliasing to `eval {foo $a $b}` doesn't work, but that does an extra level of expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can define your proc to expect both d and e as input parameters with a default value (e.g. empty string) e.g.

```
proc foo {a b c {d ""} {e ""} }.....
```

If you're going to have an unkown number of input parameters you can use the word `args`, which will create a list containing each value in `args` e.g.

```
   proc foo {a b c args } {
     foreach bar $args {
       #do whatever...
     }
   }
```

cheers
Brian

Comment: Currently, defaulted parameters can only be at the end of the argument list (except for a trailing `args`).

Answer (score 1):

If by "receives the same arguments" you mean that you are repeatedly passing the same values for `$a`, `$b`, and `$c`, then one option you have is to use globals instead of function parameters.  Store values in them before calling your function, and then your function call simplifies down to `foo $d`, etc.