# Is it possible to include a package conditionally?

Tags: tcl

It will be easier to explain using an example in C.  When you build an application in C(or C++, etc) you can build a "release" one that would not include some code that you would have in an none release one.  Ex: test code, etc.

I'm trying to do similar in TCL.  We have some tracing functions that I would like to be empty shell when in "release".

So I thought I could use two different package to do that and use one in release and one in designer so designer could use a "define" or something similar.

I know I could also "replace" each functions using "rename" and "alias" but my application start many threads(and there is one interpreter per thread) so I would have to replace multiple functions in multiple threads and that make things more complicated, I think.  I thought that instead using two different package would do a "one shot solve them all" kind of solution.

Thanks

Comment: Did you review this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006192/equivalent-of-define-in-tcl

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest techniques is to put some extra magic in the `pkgIndex.tcl` script for the package. Usually it looks something like (`cookiejar` is a little package I wrote that's in 8.7):

```
package ifneeded cookiejar 0.1 [list source [file join $dir cookiejar.tcl]]
```

But if you want to make things more conditional, you can do instead:

```
if {[info exist ::developermode]} { # Or however you want to detect it!
    package ifneeded cookiejar 0.1 [list source [file join $dir cookiejar-dev.tcl]]
} else {
    package ifneeded cookiejar 0.1 [list source [file join $dir cookiejar-release.tcl]]
}
```

You can then have two implementations, one a version for development and another for release; in your case, the release version should probably be just some empty stand in functions that provide the same API but do nothing. (You could not provide any commands at all, or make things inconsistent, but that's likely to cause code that works in development to fail in prod.)

---

If it helps, note that if you define a procedure like this:

```
proc someCommand {args} {}
```

(That is, it just takes `args` as its formal argument and has an empty body.) then Tcl will make that procedure be removed entirely from the runtime bytecode of your procedures that use it. This is probably going to be very useful to you; it lets your production code refer to your debugging helpers, yet have no (meaningful) cost for doing so.

Comment: In fact, the tcllib logger package uses that above empty proc body trick to eliminate costs for disabled logging code.